# Place Image and NavBar side by side - CSS/BootStrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a Nav Bar where the image is on the left and the nav bar is on the right - I am using bootstrap and I cannot get them to be placed side by side

The nav bar is below the image on the right

Here is my Current Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Soni's Computer Repair</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

            <div class="container">
                <img src="Final.png" style="height:50px; width:auto;"/>
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add class="pull-left" on the image and check how it turns out.

Comment: @f01 - That works however, the nav bar goes up slightly when in mobile version, so it doesnt act like it did before where the nav bar appears below the logo

Answer (score 0):

Here [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/bdwpmg10/)

You can always use the `.navbar-brand` class for this.

And also to place the `img` according to where you want. See the example I added the **id** `brandImage` and here is the `css` :

```
#brandImage{
    width: 45px;
    margin-top: -12px;
}
```